# How to hide the empty row in a ListView?

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a listview and I add many items into that list. However, when I scroll down to the last item, there's an empty row. I don't know how to get rid of it.
Thanks
[This is the picture of it](http://img21.imageshack.us/i/capturezbm.png/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed the empty space at the bottom of the ListView isn't an item. It has got to do something with the layout. More specifically, I'm suspecting the layout as managed by the scrollbar. When fiddling around with the `Margin` property of the list, sometimes the empty space at the bottom isn't there. I tried `Margin="10"`. Ofcourse this isn't a solution, but it indicates where the problem lies a bit better.

---

I found it, **this is space which is reserved for the horizontal scrollbar.**
I tried disabling it with the `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"` property, but this didn't remove the space.

Comment: Again, the scrollbar doesn't seem to be the real reason, but just as with Margin, it influences whether or not the empty space is there. When you resize the window when the horizontal scrollbar is there, you get some more random behavior with empty space there/not there. :O ... I haven't got a clue anymore what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I will try to set the above values to what you recommend. In my opinion, the empty row could be a null item ?!?

Comment: @user586981: I have the same empty space, and I made sure I didn't have a null item. The settings I mentioned won't help you, they just indicate that the problem is layout/style related.

Answer (score 3):

When I had this happen, adding this to the ListView fixed it:

`<ListView ... ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"> ... </ListView>`

Comment: Fixed the issue I was having with ListBox as well.

Answer (score 0):

It may be better if you applied an IValueConverter implementation to filter the empty rows out of the ListBox to prevent changing your source collection.

Comment: Actually, what I did is adding each item into the Listview.Items. I don't know whether changing the source collection could affect the rows!